# SSL with Protractor and PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, ssl, phantomjs, protractor

I am trying to work PhantomJS with Protractor with the web application being hosted on https.  I need to specify a cert in order for this to work.  Here is my protractor config file:

```
exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the location of this config.
  specs: [
  'spec/*.js',
'spec/**/*.js'
],

capabilities: {
browserName: 'phantomjs',
'phantomjs.cli.args':['--ssl-certificates-path=cert.p12','--ignore-ssl-errors=true']
},

// A base URL for your application under test. Calls to protractor.get()
// with relative paths will be prepended with this.
baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3000',

jasmineNodeOpts: {
  onComplete: null,
  isVerbose: false,
  showColors: true,
  includeStackTrace: true,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
}
};
```

The result from the terminal is just a lot of: 
    17:00:56.340 INFO - Executing: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []])
    17:00:56.346 INFO - Done: [execute script: return window.location.href;, []]"

There seems to be an acceptSslCerts option that is pushed into the logs but I have no idea how to set it:

[INFO  - 2014-09-30T21:00:56.239Z] Session [df2bf1e0-48e4-11e4-a415-8755c19a8d30] -    Session.negotiatedCapabilities -   {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.7","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.1.0","platf    orm":"mac-unknown-64bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"**acceptSslCerts**":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}

Protractor itself throws this error:

Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {"message":"Can't find variable: angular"

Any ideas?